# How to pass props via Vue 3 Router link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, router, quasar

I'm trying to pass props to a link router and a child component but I'm getting a warning "Missing required prop: "aircraft"

```
//routes.js
const routes = [
  {
      path: 'aircraftsForm/:id',
      component: () => import('../components/AircraftComponent.vue'),
      props: true
    }
 ]
// Parent component
const details = ref([
    {
      id: 1,
      tail: '501'
   },
{
      id: 2,
      tail: '502'
   }
])
<template>
    <AircraftsFormComponent :details="details"/>
</template>

// First Child component
const props = defineProps(['details'])
<q-table
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="id"
      flat bordered
      >
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <q-tr :props="props">
<router-link 
     :to="{ 
      path: `aircraftsForm/${props.row.id}`,
      params: { aircraft: props.row }
     }" >
  </router-link>
</q-table>

// Second child component
<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    aircraft: {
      required: true,
      type: Object
    }
  })

</script> 

<template>
  <div>
    <p>Aicraft</p>
    <p>tail {{ aircraft.tail }} </p> 
  </div>
</template>
```

"

I'm expecting to have the props rendered and initialised in a child component for it has a params defined in a router link using vue 3 and Quasar

Comment: It's unclear how this code is related. "router link component" and "Child component" - which ones are they exactly?

Comment: And a parent is AircraftComponent or? If the question relies on a hierarchy of routes from the previous question, consider updating the current one with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as it really depends on this

Comment: Parent compoent has a single child component in a template, and this child component has a routerl link inside with a lingk to the second child component