# How to pass props via router link in Vue 3 Quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, router, quasar

I've reformatted the previous question with this one.

I'm having a parent component with a sjingle child component. This child component has a router link to another child component. The issue is that I can't see the props passed with a router link. having the error " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tail')"

```
//routes.js
const routes = [
  {
      path: 'aircraftsForm/:id',
      component: () => import('../components/AircraftComponent.vue'),
      props: true
    }
 ]
// Parent component
const details = ref([
    {
      id: 1,
      tail: '501'
   },
{
      id: 2,
      tail: '502'
   }
])
<template>
    <AircraftsFormComponent :details="details"/>
</template>

// First Child component
const props = defineProps(['details'])
<q-table
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="id"
      flat bordered
      >
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <q-tr :props="props">
<router-link 
     :to="{ 
      path: `aircraftsForm/${props.row.id}`,
      params: { aircraft: props.row }
     }" >
  </router-link>
</q-table>

// Second child component
<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    aircraft: {
      required: true,
      type: Object
    }
  })

</script> 

<template>
  <div>
    <p>Aicraft</p>
    <p>tail {{ aircraft.tail }} </p>    //can't see the contnent here
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm expecting to see the rendered props in a router link

Comment: The question has the same problem as the previous one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77453422 , you could edit it instead of posting a dupe question. It remains unclear how exactly these components are related. "child" is ambiguous. This is essential because you rely on their relationship regarding the ways the props are passed through the app. If they are child *routes*, code should reflect this. . You saw your own code so you how how it works, other users didn't. It should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , i.e. enough code to reproduce the problem from scratch